# how to run cmd like del c:\myapp\*\log\* /s /q

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to delete all the files located in folders named \log\ . This folder can be everywhere (at any levels) in sub directories

ideally i want to do something like

```
  del c:\myapp\*\log\* /s /q
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: Your code does not match your question requirements, it appears to be attempting to delete txt files not all files and there appears to be unwanted whitespace following one of your forward slashes. Please [revisit you question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51267585/edit) and clarify things better so that we can provide the specific help your require. Additionally, you are supposed to attempt the task yourself and  explain what happened which did not meet your requirements, you haven't done that, you've simply posted some code, with no proper explanation!

Comment: @Compo : yes sorry i updated the question

Comment: No, you fixed one issue with whitespace and one which chooses those files whose name includes a period. _(your title also contains the whitespace issue!)_ Additionally, you say that the `'folder can be anywhere'` but your code suggests that it will only be at a specific level, _(i.e. a grandchild)_, of `C:\myapp`, please clarify!

Comment: @Compo : i correct again, yes sample is not working, it's just to gave an idea :(

Comment: Please consider providing the directory level/location clarification I asked for in my previous comment!

Comment: What about this: `for /D /R "C:\myapp" %I in ("log") do if exist "%~I\" del /S /Q "%~I\*.*"` (supposing you only want to delete files which are immediate children of the `log` found folders)

Comment: At the Command Prompt, this may even come in useful, `WMIC FSDir Where "Name Like 'C:\\myapp\\%' And FileName='log'" Get Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single line example from the Command Line, `cmd.exe`:

```dos
For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Dir /B/S/AD "C:\myapp\log" 2^>Nul') Do @Del /A/F/S/Q "%A\*"
```

---

If you want it inside a batch file, `*.cmd`|`*.bat`:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/AD "C:\myapp\log" 2^>Nul') Do @Del /A/F/S/Q "%%A\*"
```

Comment: thanks @Compa it's work ! i don't know how it's can work when you gave "C:\myapp\log" but it's work and found well directory like C:\myapp\xxx\log

Answer (score 0):

Here is a command that can be used in a .bat file script. When you are confident that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Filter 'log' | " ^
    "ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.PSPath | Remove-Item -WhatIf }"
```

Yes, it can be sorter and more cryptic and more expensive to maintain. Almost as much fun as a .bat FOR loop.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "gci -di -rec -filt 't' | %% { gci -file $_.PSPath | ri -WhatIf }"
```